# How can I fuzzy search with a keyword and return the matched substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzy-search

I'd like to be able to find and replace in a fuzzy way. So I need to do a fuzzy search of text and return a fuzzy match to a keyword, but i'm struggling to find an implementation for this. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
text = 'The sunset is a lovely colour this evening'
keyword = 'Color'
desired_result = colour
text.replace(desired_result, keyword)
print(text)
The sunset is a lovely Color this evening
```

To complicate matters the phrases that need to be replaced could be more than one word, so splitting won't work.

I've tried FuzzyWuzzy's process function, but this only will return the keyword not the match. For example:

```
process.extractOne("This sunset is a lovely colour this evening", "Color")
("Color", 90)
```

I need the match in the text so I can replace.

Python's Regex can do fuzzy matching but performance is a concern and it doesn't seem to work for me with full phrase.

```
text = 'The sunset is a lovely colour this evening'
term = 'Color'
r = regex.compile('('+text +'){e<=5}')
print(r.match(term ))
None
```

Comment: performance will generally be pretty bad for fuzzy methods. Are your words going to be similar only because of the upper/lowercase differences or will there be misspellings too to handle? If former, fuzzy matching is overkill and you might be better off doing case insensitive matches. If latter, it will be an imperfect solution.

Comment: [`fuzzy-search`](https://fuzzysearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#simple-example) would give you the indices in the string which you could then use, you've tagged it but doesn't look like you're using it.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh That's true, but I'm using fuzzywuzzy (with python levenshtein) to search through a list of 1000 terms and return matches and for my use case it's fast enough. There will be misspellings and  upper/lowercase differences between the keywords and the text. I can see by using FuzzyWuzzy that it does what I want in terms of matching, it just doesn't return the match.

Comment: @Sayse Funny enough fuzzy-search is the closet thing I've found (tag was by accident). It doesn't' return the match but rather the start and the end of the match. Which is okay in most cases, but in some cases it will not match a full word. For example, you search 'Water' in a text 'A cold glass of water' and it returns 'ater'.

Comment: @Spooknik - That doesn't sound correct... if you look at the example in the link above you'd see you could do `mystring[start:end]` to get the given match

Comment: @Sayse Okay, the not matching to a full word was my mistake. The start and end it returns of course start at zero and I was counting the line characters which start at 1. 

The next challenge is to parse the output of fuzzy-search. It returns a list in this format: `[Match(start=23, end=29, dist=1)]` I'll have to extract the ints for start and end somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using fuzzy search you can use `find_near_matches` to get the indices of matches, and then use a list comprehension from that to get the actual strings used

```
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches
my_string = 'aaaPATERNaaa'
matches = find_near_matches('PATTERN', my_string, max_l_dist=1)

print([my_string[m.start:m.end] for m in matches])
```